# Values not printing after explode

Tags: php, explode

I have this piece of code --

```
  $var = $family [$counter];

  var_dump($var);

  $a=explode('/',$var);
```

the output of "var_dump($var);" is

> http://pastebin.com/6m3ytWXZ

now i am doing explode and printing --

```
var_dump($a);
print $a[2];
```

the output of the above two lines is --

> http://pastebin.com/k68DAk5w

and when I do print $a[2]; i dont get any `output`.

why is it so ?
Please guide..!!

Comment: Are you really sure that's what you've got? http://ideone.com/k4tfz9

Comment: `$a[2]` is `pastebin.com` for me

Comment: Why is the first url that you get from var_dump (http://pastebin.com/6m3ytWXZ), different from the url that you get from the second var_dump (http://pastebin.com/k68DAk5w)? In order to get a consistent solution, we need to see a consistent example!

Comment: I can see output printed at [bottom](http://pastebin.com/k68DAk5w). i.e. "hostAgentFeatures", "layer3Features" etc after your array

Comment: yes.. actually when I use var_dump i see the desired output on browser but when i do print_r i dont

Comment: @Rikesh ..  actually when I use var_dump i see the desired output on browser but when i do print_r i dont

Comment: Can you post more relevant code ? Or create a demo with issue  you facing at http://ideone.com/ ?

Comment: @Rikesh (demo)(http://ideone.com/IAToaE)

like here when I comment the line //var_dump($a); i get the output as "hostAgentFeatures" but when i run my desired code on my localhost I don't get the output when i comment the line //var_dump($a);

Comment: Ya so it seems working. What is issue ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try `echo` ??

```
echo $a[2];
```

**UPDATED**

```
<?php
$var = "scripts/testSuite/hostAgentFeatures/ping/BasicFunctionality/IPv4/pingHostOnSubnetWithNoGateway.tcl";

$a = explode('/',$var);

print $a[2];

?>
```

Output

```
hostAgentFeatures
```

Check it here:

https://eval.in/163695

Comment: i have checked your : http://pastebin.com/6m3ytWXZ
why it is showing 3 string? You need to post your complete code. so i can check better.

Answer (score 0):

First print_r($a);
then which value u want to display put arrayname[key];

echo $a[2];

Answer (score -1):

should be cannot use print because this is an array. You can try `print_r` or `var_dump` your `$a[2]`.

```
print_r($a[2])
```

**or**

```
var_dump($a[2])
```

Comment: even with print_r i dont see the output

Comment: this is what I get from the answer i given to you. I do not see that having problem on my answer.